# Same SQL Query returning 2 different results

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a java application that does a SQL query against an Oracle database, that for some reason gives way less values when executed from the SQL Developer and from the application itself.

Now to the technicalities. The application produces a connection to the db using a wrapper library that employs c3p0. The c3p0 config has been checked, so we know that this things can't be:

-Pointing to wrong database/schema

-Restricted user

Then there's the query:

```
select to_char(AGEPINDW.TRANSACTION.TS_TRANSACTION,'yyyy-mm') as     Time,result, count(*) as TOTAL, sum(face_value) as TOTAL_AMOUNT
from AGEPINDW.TRANSACTION
where (ts_transaction >= to_timestamp(to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'yyyy-mm'),'yyyy-mm') 
   and ts_transaction < to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-mm'),'yyyy-mm')) and service_id in (2,23)
group by to_char(AGEPINDW.TRANSACTION.TS_TRANSACTION,'yyyy-mm'), result;
```

It doesn't have any parameter and is executed via your standard PreparedStatement. Yet the return from the app is wrong and I don't know what may be. Any suggestions?

Comment: Server time and time zone?

Comment: I would assume that `to_timestamp(to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'yyyy-mm'),'yyyy-mm') ` is giving you some funny results because of different NLS settings. What exactly is the intention of that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Appears to get a timestamp value for the start of previous month, i.e. 1st of previous month at midnight.

Comment: Time for you to debug. Create a small Java test program that does nothing but run that query. If it returns same as your normal app, you now have an MCVE, otherwise you have narrowed issue to setup of normal app. If test program returns wrong data, remove `group by` and run in test app and SQL Developer and see where discrepancy is.

Comment: Try `trunc(trunc(current_timestamp, 'month') -1, 'month')` or `trunc(add_months(current_timestamp, -1), 'month')`which avoids converting back and forth between strings, dates and timestamps

Comment: The intention of the query is obtaining all the values of the last month (it's a monthly report query). And yes, I suspect that the problem is because of the sysdate thing, although I still don't have any evidence of it. I'm gonna try both the dedicated app and the trunc solutions and see if it gives any more funny business.